# Target high-density mobile screens with CSS media queries

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries, screen

Currently I'm using this media query for targeting mobile screens:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {}
```

With this meta tag in the html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

It works fine on most devices, like iPhone, but when visiting the site from high-density devices like, Samsung S6-7 and so on, it serves the desktop version, with super tiny interface. If I change it to this:

```
@media  only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
    only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 13/10),
    only screen and (min-resolution: 120dpi) {}
```

It solves layout problems, boxes, containers, etc. looks the same, but UI is still super small.

How can I make the site look the same from all mobile devices (in portrait mode) regardless of actual hardware pixel densities?

Answer (score 0):

It is now working on the S7 with this setup:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 4),
       only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 4),
       only screen and (device-width: 360px),
       only screen and (device-width: 640px),
       only screen and (orientation: portrait)
```

But it also works on an iPhone 6, that has a device-pixel-ratio of 2...

I don't know why it is working.

Comment: Yes, that works on my Galaxy S10 too. But how do I negate all that? I'd like to use <link rel="stylesheet" media="... to link to one style sheet for mobile devices and a different <link for normal screens. Your answer would be much appreciated.